# Seeking the Recommendation on Complexity Theory books

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, computational-complexity, book-recommendation, computational-mathematics

S.E advisers,

I am a rising college junior in US with a major in mathematics and an aspiring applied mathematician in the fields of theoretical computing. I just recently got a research project on the complexity theory about the algebraic computation, approximation, and measure theory. I am curious if there is both introductory and comprehensive books on the complexity theory with specific focus on my area. Could you guide me?

Sincerely,

PK

Comment: Sipser's *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

The professor who assigned the project should be happy to provide appropriate references.

I do not know about your particular fieds, but for general complexity theory the classic is [Papadimitriou](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201530821) and the modern is [Arora-Barak](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521424267).